# upload media files to remote server with wordpress media uploader?

Tags: wordpress

I tried to search Wordpress plugins but with no luck. Is it possible ?

**Example :**

> Cdn hosting ftp password : 123456 ftp user name : ftp@domain.com ip :
>   23.23.23.23

i changed my upload dir setting on media setting ( in wp dashboard )

like ;

> `http://cdn.domain2.com`

How can we do it ?

Finally;

When i upload my images media uploader says uploaded but there is no files in my cdn host ?

Is that possible ? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hey try the "remote upload" plugin it might help you.

link to the plugin: http://codecanyon.net/item/remote-upload-wordpress-plugin/3159604